# What's the difference between Indoor and Outdoor Omni Wifi Antenna

Tags: wireless-networking

I have been a bit frustrated with the differences between an outdoor / indoor omni wifi 9 dbi antenna. For example these two:

1.) http://www.ebay.com/itm/9dBi-High-Gain-Booster-15-inch-OMNI-Directional-SMA-Screw-On-Swivel-Antenna-/390633183167?pt=US_Directional_Network_Antennas&hash=item5af38d57bf

2.) http://www.ebay.com/itm/Alfa-9-dBi-AOA-2409TF-outdoor-Wi-Fi-omni-directional-antenna-N-female-connector-/130863889049?pt=US_Networking_Boosters_Extenders_Antennas&hash=item1e78187a99

I know that the outdoor one has different connector, a bit taller and has a casing for weather-proof. Though I still don't understand the fact that if I get the outdoor one, will it get me more range than the indoor one? Like if i was to put both antenna in the same position will the outdoor one get further than the indoor one?

Comment: In general the antennas will be similarly limited by FCC regulations.  There is usually a benefit from elevating the antenna, but otherwise they should perform the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. 9dBi is 9dBi. Radio waves don't know the difference between indoor and outdoor.